# Where to find detailed info of how to exploit known vulnerabilities?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, cve

With most vulnerabilities, I see just summaries and not much detail about what is happening.

- Is there a good location where you can find demos of CVEs?

For example, a CVE would say that the router login screen can be exploited to gain credentials, but I cannot find details on what header/cookie/post values to send in order to exploit a certain thing. That is what I wanted to see.

I also wonder:

- Why can't I find CVE exploit explanations on Google? Is it illegal to show demos of exploits?

Comment: Then I think it's more of a language issue. You want to know how to ***exploit*** the vulnerability. You want to use the term "exploit" and "proof of concept" and "POC" in your searches.

Comment: Can you provide a CVE where you don't get the info you expect?

Comment: @schroeder the language / terms you mentioned helps, thanks. An example CVE would be `CVE-2020-11445`.

Comment: I generally search on GitHub to see if a proof-of-concept is publicly available.

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be a few issues here that are coming into play. You suggest the specific CVE: [CVE-2020-11445](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2020-11445)

This CVE has no patch, therefore, any publicly known exploit means that all those devices are in danger, leading to harm to everyone who runs one of these devices.

This CVE details also appear to be closely guarded ("an unknown code block"), so it might be difficult to devise an exploit to show.

There are hundreds of thousands of CVEs and not all of them are exploitable and not all of them have known exploits.

If there are exploits to learn from, you can find them better by using the search terms: "exploit", "proof of concept", and "poc". These terms with the CVE number will help you find the exploits you seek, if there are any that are publicly known.

Answer (score 1):

Security issues might be found by the vendor or by some third party.

It is of course not in the interest of the vendor to show how the issue can be exploited, at least as long as there are still customers out there which might be affected. That's why vendors usually don't provide demos or exploits for the issues they found and fixed themselves.

As for issues found by third parties: their interest is usually in the vendor fixing the problem and also get some publicity to show their own expertise. Providing an easy to use demo or exploit for this is not actually needed, but there are often deeper technical explanations which allow other experts to reproduce the issue. Note though that all of this takes time, so it will only be done if the perceived gain matches the needed effort.

In other words: for many issues there is not much motivation to freely provide an easy to use demo or exploit which others can simply use.

> Why can't I find CVE demonstrations on Google, is it illegal to show demos of vulnerabilities ?

It is not illegal and for many issues technical explanations are available which one can use as the base for creating a demo. But you might need to have sufficient expertise to understand the issue and follow the explanation, i.e. usually not a simple download demo and run it.